# How to select an auto incremented field in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

First of all, there are similar questions but I couldn't find a satisfied answer.

I have a `users` table and there are **id**, **name**, **surname** and **city** as its columns. **id** is auto-incremented. When a user fills fields of a form and submits the form, a record is created in database obviously.

I want return the id of user. I think, neither `SELECT TOP 1 id FROM users ORDER BY id DESC` nor selecting last inserted id is the answer because there may be many creation at the same time.

In a nutshell, is there a way to select an auto-incremented field while creating it?

Comment: `[...]First of all, there are similar questions, but I couldn't find a satisfied answer[...]` Which questions, and why weren't they helpfull? MySQL itself has [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) and the API you use to communicate with mysql most likely has something similar, where you can request the `LAST_INSERT_ID`.

Comment: @t.niese The answers which say use `SELECT TOP 1 id FROM users ORDER BY id DESC` and "select the last inserted id". They weren't helpful because when there are two record at almost the same time, it can return the wrong id. That's what I think. Of course I could be wrong but answers are not satisfied the like I said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the last insert ID, either through the driver (eg [`mysqli_insert_id`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php)) or by doing `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()`.

This will return the autoincrement value of the previous query of *this connection*. So if another user, with another connection, has inserted a row in the mean time it doesn't change the last insert id.

Comment: The part of "**this connection**" of the sentence is important. I suppose that's what looked. My concern is about this.

Answer (score 0):

Try the MySQL functions
 `LAST_INSERT_ID()` or `mysql_insert_id()`

Those work connection specific.